# Only show entries with no pending approval

Tags: publisher

I'm using publisher, and was wondering if it's possible to filter entries by approval status. We only want to show published entries with no pending approvals.

I'm getting a lot of incomplete entries.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation you'll see an {has_pending_approval} variable. http://boldminded.com/add-ons/publisher/template-tags

Comment: FYI, please use my official support channel. I don't handle support issues via Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can pass status in channel entries like:

```
{exp:channel entries status="pending" ....}
........
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

If you haven't pending status in you channels assigned statuses, You can simply create a status/ status group under admin section from EE back end
and assign it to your channel.

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: FYI: The question isn't about the status (as in core EE status for an entry). Publisher creates a live (published) and draft (pending) copy of an entry and the question was which of those is pending approval, not "has status of pending" (as they may well have a live published version with a different status). Thanks for adding an answer though :)